# ASP.NET Core route of a controller and the index action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I'm trying to set a route of my controller while also be able to navigate the index without typing `Index`, here's what I tried:

**My route configuration**

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

**Try #1**

```
// My controller
[Route("panel/admin")]
public class MyController...

// My index action
public IActionResult Index()...
```

Problem: This doesn't work, all the actions become accessible at `panel/admin` so I get an error saying `Multiple actions matched`.
Even when setting the route of my index action to `Route("")`, doesn't change anything.

**Try #2**

```
// My controller
[Route("panel/admin/[action]")]
public class MyController...

// My index action
[Route("")]
public IActionResult Index()...
```

Here, the index route doesn't change, it stays `panel/admin/Index`.

**What I want**

I want to be able to access my index action when navigating to `panel/admin` and I also want my other actions to work with just their method names like `panel/admin/UsersList`.

**Complete controller**

```
[Route("panel/admin/[action]")]
public class MyController
{

    [Route("")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult UsersList()
    {
        var users = _db.Users.ToList();
        return View(users);
    }

    // Other actions like UsersList

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `[Route("panel/admin/")]`? Or setting up routing at the global-app-start level?

Comment: Um yes I did, in both tries.

Comment: Can you also share your route configuration in Startup.cs (or if you have no route configuration in Startup.cs, just say that)?

Comment: @Rainbolt I added it.

Comment: You will likely have to not set the route at the controller level. Instead you will need to just apply them to the action methods instead. Action routes will always basically append to the controllers route.

Comment: I assume because you are getting `Multiple actions matched` that you have multiple actions names Index. What is the purpose of each? You might be able to annotate them with `[HttpPost]` or `[HttpGet]`.

Comment: @BinaryNexus This is a scaffolded controller and I have many more to come so setting the routes for all actions is a bit..

Comment: @Rainbolt Actually in Try #1 the `Multiple actions matched` shows that all the actions (even with different names) match my request, not just the Index one (which I only have one of).

Comment: Deleted my answer. please show us your  complete controller in your question.

Comment: @CodeNotFound Added an example of my controller.

Comment: @Haytam you are mixing up how the routes work. with `[action]` on the controller you make `Index` mandatory. Even with the empty route on the action.

Comment: @How many controllers do you have in yoru project? Your code should work

Comment: @Nkosi That's the thing, I want to know if there is a solution to what I want. Um a lot but I don't think they overlap or anything.

Comment: with attribute routing, you need to be specific about the routes otherwise you will get route conflicts. (multiple routes matching).

Comment: Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain why? @Nkosi I know that I'm just wondering wheither what I want is possible, that's all.

Comment: For the record, it was not me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

With attribute routes you have to be very specific about desired routes to avoid route conflicts. Which also means that you will have to specify all the routes. Unlike convention-based routing.

Option #1

```
[Route("panel/admin")]
public class MyController {

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")] //GET panel/admin
    [Route("[action]")]  //GET panel/admin/index
    public IActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("[action]")] //GET panel/admin/UsersList
    public IActionResult UsersList() {
        var users = _db.Users.ToList();
        return View(users);
    }

    // Other actions like UsersList
}
```

Option #2

```
[Route("panel/admin/[action]")]
public class MyController {

    [HttpGet] //GET panel/admin/index
    [Route("~/panel/admin")] //GET panel/admin        
    public IActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet] //GET panel/admin/UsersList
    public IActionResult UsersList() {
        var users = _db.Users.ToList();
        return View(users);
    }

    // Other actions like UsersList
}
```

The tilde (`~`) in `[Route("~/panel/admin")]` overrides the route prefix on the controller.

> ### Tip
>
> While using multiple routes on actions can seem powerful, it's better
> to keep your application's URL space simple and well-defined. Use
> multiple routes on actions only where needed, for example to support
> existing clients.

Comment: I guess this is as good as it can get, I like your Option #2. Thank you for your time!